# Swift : Converting inline to trailing closures in function

Tags: ios, swift, closures

So I have the following function defined:

```
public typealias RESTClosure = (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure(completionHandler : RESTClosure) {       
// code ....  
}
```

I'm able to call this function as:

```
func myResponseHandler(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void {
    // code ...
}

rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure(myResponseHandler)
```

From my understanding of Swift, however, if the final argument of a function is a closure it can be converted into a trailing closure ... but I've run into some syntax confusion:

#### Attempt #1

```
rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure() {
    println("Called with Closure")
}
```

**Error:**
*Tuples types '(response: NSURLResponse!, data NSData!, error: NSError!)' and '()' have different number of elements (3 vs. 0)*

#### Attempt #2

```
rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure() (RESTClosure.self) {  // Xcode told me to add a .self
  //...code
}
```

**Error:** *Missing argument for parameter #1 in call*

I know I'm close ... but anybody can help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameters go inside the closure, and since there's just the one argument, you can even leave out the parentheses:

```
rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure {
    (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in

    // code ...
}
```

If you're going to be accessing `self` or any properties inside the closure, you'll want to include `self` in a *capture list*, like this:

```
rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure {
    [weak self] (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in

    // code ...

    // note that self is optional inside this closure b/c of [weak self]
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: How come I can't use my typalias here?

Comment: I don't think you can use any of your arguments if you use the type alias. How would refer to the `NSURLResponse` argument in the version with your alias?

Comment: You could leave out the parameters entirely and use shorthand (`$0`, `$1`, etc) but I only use those for very short closures.

Comment: And if i wanted to capture any other variables say a private class variable?

Comment: A class variable won't be deallocated while your program is running, so it will always be safe to access `MyClass.propertyName` within a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Well this seems to compile

```
rest?.queryAllFlightsWithClosure() { RESTClosure in
   // code ...        
}
```